# compute this integral $\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos^n(\frac{x}{2})\times \cos(\frac{nx}{2})dx$

Tags: integration

I have used De Moivre's Thm and binomial expansion to get the identity:
$$ 2^n \cos^n(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{nx}{2})= {\sum_{r=0}^{n}}\binom{n}{r}\cos(rx) $$

How do I use the identity to compute the integral?

Comment: You may want to double check the identity. The left-side is an odd function, but the right-side is even.

Comment: Thanks, I have corrected my mistake.

Comment: Assuming that your equation is now correct, it looks like you are 95% done, and need only focus on indefinite integrals.  Can you compute $\int k\cos ax dx$ ?  Based on the RHS of your equation, the final answer will be the sum of a group of integrals, each of whom you can integrate separately.

Comment: Okay. I have got it.

Comment: Yes, I did it myself, the graph I checked had n=3.1, so it's important to note that extension of combinatrics/factorial won't work. So, $$n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$$ only.

Comment: I think an interesting aside would be to compute $\int_0^\pi \cos^n(\frac{x}{2})\sin(\frac {nx}{2})dx$ using an equivalent identity. My thinking indicates the integral will have different values depending if n is odd or even.